# Why loops have different runtime in leetcode?

Tags: c++, performance

Why in leetcode above loop takes more time than below one ??

```
    for(int iIndex = 0; iIndex< nums.size(); iIndex++)
    {
        if (nums[iIndex] == target) return iIndex;
    }
    
    int iIndex = 0;
    for(int x: nums)
    {
        if (x == target) return iIndex;
        iIndex++;
    }
```

Comment: Time may vary, are you sure that you had run both of them like 20 times and still observe a difference in runtime? They should produce the same assembly.

Comment: This is a matter of compiler optimization. There is no one answer for C++ in general.

Comment: *Why in leetcode...* -- The maintainers of that site would be the ones that can answer your question.

Comment: Disassemble both and compare?  That's the real world answer outside of leetcode.

Comment: What are the optimization settings?  Is it optimized for speed or space?

Comment: The runtime may vary for lot of reasons in the Online Judges. Even if you run this in your own computer, it might give different results in different runs. Also, `takes more time` vague in performance comparison.